# Jqgrid filter - column with image

Tags: jquery

I have a table which some columns are represented only by images, for example:

[image]

I wonder if it's possible to filter this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this selector for filtering td use :has

```
$("td:has(img)")
```